# Changing bin numbers `scale_*_binned()`

Tags: r, ggplot2

Following the recent release of ggplot2 v3.3.0 I am trying to understand the use of `scale_*_binned()`.

It seems that there is no clear way to specify the number of bins are used. Take the below example.

```r
library(ggplot2)

ggplot(iris, aes(Sepal.Length, Petal.Length, color = Sepal.Width)) +
    geom_point() +
    scale_color_binned()
```

[image]

```r
ggplot(iris, aes(Sepal.Length, Petal.Length, color = Sepal.Width)) +
  geom_point() +
  scale_color_binned(bins = 10)
#> Error in binned_scale(aesthetics, "steps", seq_gradient_pal(low, high, : unused argument (bins = 10)
```

<sup>Created on 2020-04-05 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

I've tried setting `bins` as an argument (based on my knowledge of `geom_histogram()`) to no avail. There is also no documentation for these functions and I seem unable to infer it from the documentation for existing scale functions.

How can we change the number of bins?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`n.breaks` is what you are looking for. See https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/ggplot2/versions/3.3.0/topics/scale_colour_gradient for options passed on via `scale_colour_steps`.

```r
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(iris, aes(Sepal.Length, Petal.Length, color = Sepal.Width)) +
    geom_point() +
    scale_color_binned(n.breaks=5)
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2020-04-05 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Comment: 2 years later and only now have i accepted the answer! sorry!